# Wordpress child theme Styles

Tags: css, wordpress, header, wordpress-theming

I created a custom child theme from the skeleton responsive wordpress theme. However, after working locally and getting everything styled perfectly no styles show up after launching the site live.

I manually added the styles from the header of my local copy out of frustration. This helped as the styles show up correctly. After manually adding the styles none of my uploaded images that are included in my database will show up. My contact form and my banners will not show up on the site. The code is in the correct place and the images are in the upload folder.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="theme-css" href="http://www.cmc.com/wp-content/themes/skeleton_wp-master/skeleton_childtheme/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
```

Above is one of 10 links that I added to my header file. I am not sure how to make the link show up using the functions file.

I do not understand how everything works fine as far as childtheme linking to parent theme `layout.css` and `skeleton.css` when working locally but when I go live it won't work any more.

Please Help!

Comment: http://tech-papers.org/how-to-create-wordpress-child-theme/

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things.. 
1. Make sure you have properly set up your child theme and activated it in the appearance menu. http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes
2. If you are still having image issues, try using paths to your images like this:
/wp-content/imagename.jpg instead of the full URL.

Answer (score 0):

How your childtheme CSS should look like:

```
/*
 Theme Name:     Twenty Thirteen Child
 Theme URI:      http://example.com/twenty-thirteen-child/
 Description:    Twenty Thirteen Child Theme
 Author:         John Doe
 Author URI:     http://example.com
 Template:       twentythirteen
 Version:        1.0.0
*/

@import url("../twentythirteen/style.css");

/* =Theme customization starts here
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
```

After you've done that you can activate it in your dashboard and you won't need to edit the header file when your parent theme is coded properly (most are).

Comment: I figured out that the header was breaking the site when I added that particular file. Also, I was using a saas and fully compressing the style sheet which took out the theme information that was needed in order to make the child work. So I had to add the important exclamation to the code to make it appear in the style sheet after it was compressed and compiled to css.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in the parent theme; in the way it has linked `style.css`.
To solve this issue, you can register and enqueue your `style.css` in `functions.php` of the child theme.
You can do so by adding the below code in functions.php of child theme:

```
// register and enqueue the stylesheet.
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_child_theme_styles' );

function register_child_theme_styles() {
wp_register_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
wp_enqueue_style( 'style' );
}
```

You can refer [**this**](http://wisdmlabs.com/blog/wordpress-child-theme-not-loading-stylesheet/) article for the same.